# How does a SQL Server Snapshot retrieve deleted record from original database?

Tags: sql-server, snapshot

I have created a snapshot, `AdventureWorksSS`.
Deleted a record after creating a snapshot.

When I query from `AdventureWorksSS`, deleted record shows up.

Where is that deleted record stored and how does Snapshot still retrieve the deleted record?

As far as I understand, snapshot is a pointer to the original database and fetches data only necessary.
Do deleted data get inserted into snapshots automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this explaines it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187054.aspx

Comment: I can see that deleted records are stored on snapshot file during "copy-on-write operation".

Answer (score 1):

Snapshot isolation level retrieves the previous row from the [Version Store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177404.aspx). The Version Store keeps track of all changes that affect a versioned row in tempdb.

Database snapshot does a copy on write of the affected pages and uses the OS [sparse files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365564(VS.85).aspx) feature.